# Создание WebSocket'а

Tags: php

Скажите пожалуйста, в чем разница между созданием веб-сокета с помощью конструкции типа:

```
$socket = stream_socket_server("tcp://{$host}:{$port}", $errorNumber, $errorString);
```

и

```
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
```

ведь, исходя из примеров, все сходиться к тому, что подключения мы получаем через метод `socket_select`? Однако первый вариант, несмотря на его популярность в Сети, у меня так и не заработал, т.к. `socket_select` ожидал в массиве сокеты, а получал, почему-то, ресурсы в р-те выполнения `stream_socket_server`.

Comment: Чисто ради интереса, у вас получилось сделать веб сокет на пхп ?

Comment: @Міша, пока нет, но надеюсь, что получится. Исходя из статей этой весьма реально.

Comment: Тогда удачи вам, меня так и не хватило на это) Сделал на .Net SignalR